# Having trouble using perl command line to do a search and replace

Tags: regex, bash, perl, search, replace

I'm using bash shell on Mac YOsemite.  I have a file that contains lines like

```
560c4f458b97330d00b0832d 5237d5eee1399d2f11005571
560c4f458b97330d00b0832e 55c4a0001b9e2d0e00032d6f
560c4f458b97330d00b0832f 55ce2e78e1055a0d008cad3c
560c4f458b97330d00b08330 55ce2e78e1055a0d008cad44
560c4f458b97330d00b08331 55ce2e78e1055a0d008cad4a
560c4f458b97330d00b08332 55c4a0001b9e2d0e00032d78
560c4f458b97330d00b08333 55c4a0001b9e2d0e00032d7b
560c4f458b97330d00b08334 55ce2e78e1055a0d008cad51
```

I’m trying to write an expression that will turn the file into a series of SQL statements.  So I tried

```
perl -pi -e “s/(.*?)\s(.*)/update my_sql_table set my_user_id = '$2' where my_user_id = '$1';/g" /tmp/myfile.csv
```

Hoping to get a file of lines line

```
update my_sql_table set my_user_id = '5237d5eee1399d2f11005571' where my_user_id = '560c4f458b97330d00b0832d';
update my_sql_table set my_user_id = '55c4a0001b9e2d0e00032d6f' where my_user_id = '560c4f458b97330d00b0832e';
```

But instead the output is one massive line of statements that look like

```
update my_sql_table set my_user_id = '' where my_user_id = '';update my_sql_table set my_user_id = '' where my_user_id = '';update my_sql_table set my_user_id = '' where my_user_id = '';update my_sql_table set my_user_id = ''
```

How can I correct my above statement to put the tokens in the right place?

Comment: If you're reading a line at a time you don't need the global modifier, try to take it out.

Comment: I removed the "g".  Although I dont' get one giant file anymore, I still don't get the tokens substituted in the right place, getting instead, "update my_sql_table set my_user_id = '' where my_user_id = '';"

Comment: Probably a bunch of extra spaces in there. Use `\S` in place of dot `.` Like `(\S+?)\s(\S+)` where the quantifier is now `+`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is simple using Perl's command-line autosplit option

```
perl -anE'print qq{update my_sql_table set my_user_id = \'$F[1]\' where my_user_id = \'$F[0]\';\n}' ids.txt
```

#### output

```sql
update my_sql_table set my_user_id = '5237d5eee1399d2f11005571' where my_user_id = '560c4f458b97330d00b0832d';
update my_sql_table set my_user_id = '55c4a0001b9e2d0e00032d6f' where my_user_id = '560c4f458b97330d00b0832e';
update my_sql_table set my_user_id = '55ce2e78e1055a0d008cad3c' where my_user_id = '560c4f458b97330d00b0832f';
update my_sql_table set my_user_id = '55ce2e78e1055a0d008cad44' where my_user_id = '560c4f458b97330d00b08330';
update my_sql_table set my_user_id = '55ce2e78e1055a0d008cad4a' where my_user_id = '560c4f458b97330d00b08331';
update my_sql_table set my_user_id = '55c4a0001b9e2d0e00032d78' where my_user_id = '560c4f458b97330d00b08332';
update my_sql_table set my_user_id = '55c4a0001b9e2d0e00032d7b' where my_user_id = '560c4f458b97330d00b08333';
update my_sql_table set my_user_id = '55ce2e78e1055a0d008cad51' where my_user_id = '560c4f458b97330d00b08334';
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd use split instead of a regex in a perl loop:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

open my $input_file, '<', 'input.txt' or die $!;

while(<$input_file>){   
        chomp;
        my @fields = split;
        print "update my_sql_table set my_user_id = $fields[1] where my_user_id = $fields[0]\n";
    }
```

Or as a one-liner:

```
perl -F: -lane 'print "update my_sql_table set my_user_id = $F[1] where my_user_id = $F[0]";' in.txt
```

Or using awk:

```
awk '{ print "update my_sql_table set my_user_id = " $2 "where my_user_id = " $1 }' < in.txt
```

Comment: Is this a Perl script?  Do I replace "<DATA>" with the name of my file?

Comment: Like the ideas of the one-liners but the first one doesn't work and the second one doens't include single quotes around the two arguments to the SQL statements.

Comment: @Dave - Great - feel free to add them yourself then

Answer (score 0):

A short shell loop (it seems a bit too much to pull in Perl to do this):

```
while read -r old new; do
    cat <<SQL_END
UPDATE my_sql_table
    SET my_user_id   = '$new'
    WHERE my_user_id = '$old';
SQL_END
done
```

Running it with the provided data in `data.in`:

```
$ sh scripts.sh <data.in
UPDATE my_sql_table
    SET my_user_id   = '5237d5eee1399d2f11005571'
    WHERE my_user_id = '560c4f458b97330d00b0832d';
UPDATE my_sql_table
    SET my_user_id   = '55c4a0001b9e2d0e00032d6f'
    WHERE my_user_id = '560c4f458b97330d00b0832e';
UPDATE my_sql_table
    SET my_user_id   = '55ce2e78e1055a0d008cad3c'
    WHERE my_user_id = '560c4f458b97330d00b0832f';
UPDATE my_sql_table
    SET my_user_id   = '55ce2e78e1055a0d008cad44'
    WHERE my_user_id = '560c4f458b97330d00b08330';
UPDATE my_sql_table
    SET my_user_id   = '55ce2e78e1055a0d008cad4a'
    WHERE my_user_id = '560c4f458b97330d00b08331';
UPDATE my_sql_table
    SET my_user_id   = '55c4a0001b9e2d0e00032d78'
    WHERE my_user_id = '560c4f458b97330d00b08332';
UPDATE my_sql_table
    SET my_user_id   = '55c4a0001b9e2d0e00032d7b'
    WHERE my_user_id = '560c4f458b97330d00b08333';
UPDATE my_sql_table
    SET my_user_id   = '55ce2e78e1055a0d008cad51'
    WHERE my_user_id = '560c4f458b97330d00b08334';
```